# How to use Tag with [OutputCache] on Controllers instead of Minimal API's

Tags: c#, .net-core, outputcache, .net-7.0

We can use Tag like that with Minimal API's `.CacheOutput(x=x.Tag("people"));` So that we can use `IOutputCacheStore.EvictByTag("people");`.

But when it comes to controllers, we have to use `[CacheOutput]` attribute which does not have 'Tag'. There is no such usage like `[CacheOutput(Tag="people)]` so that I can not use `EvictByTag()`. I don't want to migrate all my controllers to minimal API's. Is there a way to use Tag with controllers?

Answer (score 0):

`CacheOutput` builds cache policy which is applied to particular mapped endpoint. You can declare policy when adding services for output cache and pass policy name to the attribute:

```cs
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("PeopleTagPolicy", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.Tag("people")));

[OutputCache(PolicyName = "PeopleTagPolicy")]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HttpContext.Features

```
HttpContext.Features.Get<IOutputCacheFeature>()?.Context.Tags.Add("you tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

This was added in .NET 8, so you now can do:

```cs
[OutputCache(Tags = ["people"])]
```